# Accessing Tab properties from other Form

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

[image: My project picture]
I have a form 1 and form 2 in window form C#.in from 1 i have tabcontrol and function of add new tab , detect , and active tab which work fine in form 1 but not show any the in form 2.

```
public void add_tab(string str)
    {
        TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(str);
        myTabPage.Name = str;
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        active_tab(textBox1.Text);
    }
    public void active_tab(string st)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectTab(st);
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        delect(textBox1.Text);
    }
    public void delect(string st)
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveByKey(st);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. You should show us more code, like when the two Form's are created.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to be able to access tabcontrol from form1 in form2's code behind.
In that case, you either Pass the reference of form1 to form2, This can be done in multiple ways.

`var form1 = new Form1();`
`..`
`var form2 = new Form2(form1);`

Now using Form2 reference you can access tabcontrol.

Hope this was the issue you were facing.

Comment: i have added the picture of my project i thing new you can understand better what i went @PankajH

Comment: Okay, Do you want to be able to call the same methods (active_tab,delete etc) of Form1 from Form2 ?

Comment: You have not shared the code for Button 'add Form2' .

Comment: On clicking the button same function will be call like form1 f =new form1(); f.close(textbox1.text); @pankajH